# How to copy complete content on terminal to a text file using commands ?(Not for one output but everything on terminal)

Tags: command-line

How to copy complete content on terminal to a text file using commands .

Comment: I unserstand you want to copy the output of *previous* commands right? Not the output of yet to be run commands.

Comment: Are you working inside `screen` or `tmux` (maybe using `byobu`)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `screendump`.

As in the man page:

```
 screendump - dump the contents of a virtual console to stdout
```

You'll need root privileges to run screendump, so use sudo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **script**. It will basically save everything printed on the terminal in that script session.

From [man script](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html):

```
script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal. 
It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an 
interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file 
can be printed out later with lpr(1).
You can start a script session by just typing script in the terminal, all the subsequent commands and their outputs will all be saved in a file named typescript in the current directory. You can save the result to a different file too by just starting script like:
```

script output.txt
To logout of the script session (stop saving the contents), just type exit.

Here is an example:

```
$ script output.txt
Script started, file is output.txt

$ ls
output.txt  testfile.txt  foo.txt

$ exit
exit
Script done, file is output.txt
```

Now if I read the file:

```
$ cat output.txt

Script started on 2020-07-23 09:57:16+05:30
$ ls
output.txt  testfile.txt  foo.txt
$ exit
exit

Script done on 2020-07-23 09:57:34+05:30
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as terminal emulators go ( GUI ) you can select the text with mouse and switch to text editor ( be it gedit or anything else ) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Button 2</kbd> ( [Scroll wheel on mouse](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_Uq907Hmj7AE/SufJMc0IfRI/AAAAAAAABCc/DyBu2Ozndsc/mouse%20button_thumb[2].jpg?imgmax=800) and Right+Left click on touchpad )

With TTY  you could use `cat /dev/vcs1` to [dump contents of TTY1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/95916/85039).

Best approaches , however, should use terminal multiplexers such as `screen` , `tmux`, `byobu` or use `script` command to record the whole session to file.